# How to prevent HTML escaping in Clojure Reagent (Hiccup like)

Tags: clojure, reagent, hiccup

I am using ClojureScript Reagent. Which provides hiccup-like HTML generation.

I have a String with HTML:

```
(def code "<b>hello world</b>")
```

When passed to Hiccup it will be escaped and I get no bold text on my page:

```
[:div code]
```

How to pass `code` to my HTML output so it will be integrated there without being escaped?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Reagent

Use the `dangerouslysetInnerHTML` native React call

```
[:div {:dangerouslySetInnerHTML {:__html code}}])
```

### Also see:

- [Issue #14](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/issues/14)

### (real) Hiccup

You need to use the `raw-string` function from `hiccup.utils`:

```
[:div (raw-string code)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I use reagent which is hiccup-like but not realy hiccup. Therefor there is no hiccup.util namespace :-(

Comment: You have not. I have changed my question. Sorry ;-)

Comment: @Witek That's OK, next time, if you noticed that you have an edit that would invalidate existing answers, please ask a new question, linking to the old one, with explaining the difference.

Comment: It looks like there is no longer a `raw-string` function in the `hiccup.util` namespace:

http://weavejester.github.io/hiccup/hiccup.util.html

Edit: looks like it's part of v2:

https://cljdoc.org/d/hiccup/hiccup/2.0.0-alpha2/api/hiccup.util#raw-string